# Problem involving cyclic quadrilaterals and angle rotated

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

"Suppose an angle BAC is rotated about point O to a new angle B'A'C' such that AB and A'B' intersected at M and AC and A'C' intersect at N, as shown. Prove that A, A', M, N, and O all lie on a circle.
[image]"

This is a problem from Mandelbrot Competition. Regarding my attempted solution, as the angles BAC and B'A'C' measure the same and A and A' are on the same side of MN, then the quadrilateral AA'MN is cyclic. I was trying to use the same argument with point O and M or N with respect to segment AA', but I don't know how to justify this fact.

So, I hope you can give me a hint or argument to prove that O is inscribed in the same circle of the quadrilateral AA'MN. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the angle of rotation by $\alpha$.

Since the line $AB$ gets rotated into $A'B'$, the angle between $AB$ and $A'B'$ is equal to $\alpha$. For similar reason, the angle between $AO$ and $A'O$ equals $\alpha$.

Therefore $\angle A'MA = \alpha = \angle A'OA$, hence $A'OMA$ is cyclic.